# Flutter Application Stop Responsing and should kill the app and run again to work after call Random Functions in App

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-cubit

My problem only happen while im trying to use the app and click on buttons to on screen..

The application does not stop responding when I click on a specific one, what happens and this happens randomly, I do not know why

And Also Android Studio Going in infinite for loop and keeping Print in console this message
( log : null)

Screen Shot Of what happen in android studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VWJn.png

Answer (score 0):

if You Using Flutter Bloc
The Default parameter in
BlocProvider(lazy: true);
Should changing to `false` If there a lot of states used

Example :

```
 BlocProvider(
  lazy: false,// This should be false Not True
  create: (BuildContext context)=> ExampleCubitClass(),
  child: BlocConsumer<ExampleCubitClass,ExampleStatesClass>(
    listener: (context,state){},
    builder: (context,state){}
```